# An error is occuring when I try and create a controller using asp.net MVC( make sure the controller has a parameterless public constructor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, http

I have created a controller using asp.net mvc and every time my controller trys to access this controller I get an error that reads

> " An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'SMSCampaignController'. Make sure that the controller has a
>   parameterless public constructor"

When I place a parameterless constructor in the controller I get a 401 error meaning that the application cannot find the controller. The other confusing thing here is that this controller is only meant to called onClick but for some reason its being called when the application starts

Here is my controller below

```
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Security;
using Repositories.Interfaces;
using Repositories.Interfaces.Dtos;
using SimSentinel.Models;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Repositories.Interfaces.SMSCampaign;



namespace SimSentinel.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class SMSCampaignController : ApiController
   {
      private readonly ISMSCampaignRepository _smsCampaignRepository;
      public static int globalUserId;

      //public SMSCampaignController()
     // {  }

      public SMSCampaignController(ISMSCampaignRepository smsCampaignRepository)
      {
         _smsCampaignRepository = smsCampaignRepository;
      }


        [HttpPost]
      public string Post(SMSCampaignViewModel smsCampaign)
      {
         if (smsCampaign == null)
         {
            return null;
         }
         var smsCampaignDto = new SMSCampaign(
             smsCampaign.smsCampaignId,
             smsCampaign.costCentreId,
             smsCampaign.campaignName,
             smsCampaign.msisdn,
             smsCampaign.message,
             smsCampaign.createdAt,
             smsCampaign.campaignStartDate,
             smsCampaign.campaignExpiryDate,
             smsCampaign.clientManager);
         //_organisationEmployeeRepository.UpdateEmployee(employeeDto, employee.passwordCheck);
            _smsCampaignRepository.SaveSMSCampaign(smsCampaign.smsCampaignId, smsCampaign.costCentreId, smsCampaign.campaignName, smsCampaign.msisdn, smsCampaign.message, smsCampaign.createdAt, smsCampaign.campaignStartDate, smsCampaign.campaignExpiryDate, smsCampaign.clientManager);

            return "Your profile was succesfully updated";

      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set up dependency injection? If not, then you can't have a controller constructor with parameters.

Comment: Which IoC container are you using?

Comment: @Zidane, This is because you have injected `ISMSCampaignRepository ` as dependency but did not resolve this with DI provider.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I doubt that is why, the error suggests that there is no DI set up at all.

Comment: An example of setting up the StructureMap dependecy injection in asp net webapi: https://exceptionnotfound.net/setting-up-dependency-injection-in-web-api-with-structuremap/